# FileNotFoundException when using dll method

Tags: c#, dll, filenotfoundexception

in Visual Studio I have a solution with several projects. In one project I added a reference to another project. All fine. I can see the namespaces/classes of the another project in autocomplete, etc.

When I try to do

```
OtherProjectNamespace.Class a = new OtherProjectNamespace.Class();
```

I'm getting this:

```
Could not load file or assembly '**OtherProjectNamespace**, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

There is no line, nothing, I tried try... catch around the new line and is not even catching the exception.

What could be the cause?

Thanks,
Carlos

Comment: Have you added a reference to the other project?

Comment: Yes, and I'm trying the instantiation in another thread ... just in case.

Comment: How did you add the reference, is it a copy of the file, or the output of the solution.  It sounds like you just have a copy, and the file was deleted, try confirming the reference is correct.

Comment: Hey, I just added the reference to another project(not the project using the dll, there are 4 projects) and It worked. Maybe is because I'm using reflection to load the dll etc, and then creating a thread to work. What should I do with this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some possible directions:

1. Does the class you are trying to create have any dependency on a class in another assembly? If it does, try adding a reference to the third assembly.
2. Did the assembly get copied to the running directory of your application? Ensure that the `Copy Local` property of the reference is set to `true`.
3. If you still don't resolve the problem, use a tools such as Fusion Log View (comes with Visual Studio, run `fuslogvw.exe` from VS command line) to get the exact name of the file that was missing, and the locations from which the CLR tried to load it. Maybe this way you'll find another file that you need to copy.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

In the project references, change the "Specific Version" property to false. Right click on the project and select Clean. Then rebuild the project.